# Query UTxO with PostgreSQL (cardano-db-sync)

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-db-sync

How can I query the last UTxO from an address on PostgreSQL (I used `cardano-db-sync`) like I would do using cardano-cli:

> cardano-cli query utxo --address addr_test1vpm4uhupwxc4jjea6c6s5p0t80znlfr03xj4ewygnjtxd3cyjdv8x --testnet-magic 1097911063

I also want to know more information regarding this transaction like who sent, etc.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find an answer to his? I have the exact same query from cardano-db-sync but have not found a way to do this - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the basic utxo you would get from `query utxo`, you want a join from utxo_view to tx table.

`SELECT * FROM utxo_view INNER JOIN tx ON tx.id = utxo_view.tx_id WHERE address = 'addr1...'`

To get the list of txins sending the tx, you need to join that to tx_in and then rejoin that to the tx_out table and it will return a row for every output that's being used as an input, but usually at this point of complexity with SQL queries I start to throw for loops into my code.